# Typescript types on rest params from argument

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to tell typescript about the types of rest params based on the signature of a function passed?

```
function myFunc(a: string, b: number) { /* ... */ }

function callFn(passedFn: (args...: any[]), ...args: any[]) {
  passedFn(...args)
}

callFn(myFunc, 1, 2) // should be a warning
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? forget syntax, just tell us what are your reasons/features

Answer (score 0):

Following code shows that you get compile error, because you will lose type control under args.

```
interface ICallback 
{ 
    (a: string, b: number): void
}

class Test
{    
    public CallFn(passedFn: ICallback, ...args: any[]): void
    {
        passedFn(args); // error
        passedFn("1", 2);
    }    
}

class Callback
{    
    public MyFunction = (a: string, b: number) => 
    {
         alert("it's working");
    }
}

let testIntance = new Test();
let callbackIntance = new Callback();

testIntance.CallFn(callbackIntance.MyFunction, 1, 2);
```

You have to handle exceptions and try parse into typed variables.

```
class Test
{    
    public CallFn(passedFn: ICallback, ...args: any[]): void
    {
        //passedFn(args); // error

        let hasTwoArguments = args && args.length && args.length === 2;
        if(!hasTwoArguments)
        {
            return;
        }

        let firstArgument: string = args[0];
        let secondArgument: number = parseInt(args[1]);

        passedFn(firstArgument, secondArgument);
    }
}
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/joeyczech/bu71ff0y/)